# Player and Monster miss together in my game

Tags: c#, math, random

In my C# game TextQuest, The fighting system is in progress now and I ran into a problem.
If the player misses the Monster misses too (always at the same time). Here is the used code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Monster_Class mc = new Monster_Class();
        Account_Class ac = new Account_Class();
        if (hitOrMiss())
        {
            int hit = -1;
            hit = mc.hitAmount(ac.getAtk(Properties.Settings.Default.CurrentUser), mc.getDef(monster));
            mhealth -= hit;
            if (hit == -1)
            {
                setText("You missed.");
            }
            else
            {
                setText("You hit " + hit + ".");
            }
            monsterHit();
            update();
        }
        else
        {
            setText("You missed.");
            monsterHit();
        }
    }

private void monsterHit()
{
    Monster_Class mc = new Monster_Class();
    Account_Class ac = new Account_Class();
    if (hitOrMiss())
    {
        int hit = -1;
        hit = mc.hitAmount(mc.getAtk(monster), ac.getDef(Properties.Settings.Default.CurrentUser));
        phealth -= hit;
        if (hit == -1)
        {
            addText(monster + " missed.");
        }
        else
        {
            addText(monster + " hit " + hit + ".");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        addText(monster + " missed.");
    }
}

private bool hitOrMiss()
{
    bool hit = true;
    Random rand = new Random();
    if (rand.Next(101) < 15)
    {
        hit = false;
    }
    return hit;
}

public int hitAmount(int Atk, int Def)
{
    int hit = -1;
    Random rand = new Random();
    int deturm = rand.Next(6);
    try
    {
        hit = ((Atk + deturm * 3) / Def + 1) / 2;
        if (hit == 0)
        {
            hit = 1;
        }
    }
    catch { }
    return hit;
}
```

Also if you have a better Idea for the amount of damage done please let me know. since I just kinda threw numbers and symbols together

Comment: They always miss at the same time. If the player misses the monster shouldn't always miss too. and if the player hits the monster should still be able to miss

Comment: Kind of unrelated to the question but... that `try` block is bad. The only exception that can come out of that is a divide by zero error, and you can check that with an `if` statement (`if (Def == 0) return -1;`) - *if* you didn't mean for the `+1` to be applied before the `/` (and assuming `Def` is >= 0). If that you did, you need brackets around it.

Comment: I had it there because I was changing the math around trying to find something that worked and I plan on changing it some more later so I left it there for now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to create a new Random object every time you need a random number. Otherwise I suspect you will get always the same number! Define a global Random object once and use it in every request for random numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much I didn't even think of trying that.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a side hint I would change the design a little bit, something like:

```
bool hitOrMiss(Entity attacker, Entity defender)
{
  // do your calcs
}

int doAttack(Entity attacker, Entity defender)
{
  if (hitOrMiss(attacker, defender)) {
    // calculate damage
    return dmg;
  }
  else
    return 0;
}

private void attachPhase(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Player player = ...
  Monster monster = ...

  int playerDmg = doAttack(player, monster);
  int monsterDmg = doAttack(monster, player);

  if (playerDmg > 0) {

  }

  if (monsterDmg > 0) {

  }
}
```